# Download multiple FTP files like d*.txt in ruby

Tags: ruby

I need to connect to a ftp site and download a bunch of files( max 6) named as D*.txt.
could you please help me code this in Ruby ?
The following code just

```
ftp = Net::FTP::new("ftp_server_site")
ftp.login("user", "pwd")
ftp.chdir("/RemoteDir")
fileList= ftp.nlst
ftp.getbinaryfile(edi, edi)
ftp.close
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way would be to loop through the list of files in `fileList`.

Here is an example (untested):

```
ftp = Net::FTP::new("ftp_server_site")
ftp.login("user", "pwd")
ftp.chdir("/RemoteDir")
fileList = ftp.list('D*.txt')
fileList.each do |file|
  ftp.gettextfile(file)
end
ftp.close
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Correct. That's what a FTP client does for an `mget`.

Answer (score 6):

Array of filenames in dir you can get by "[nlst](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/Net/FTP.html#method-i-nlst)" method:

```
files = ftp.nlst('*.zip')

files.each do |file|
  puts file
end

#=> first.zip, second.zip, third.zip, ...
```

Answer (score 3):

That solution did not work for me, although it may depend on the FTP server.  For me, ftp.list returns results similar to `ls -l` on Linux.  I used the following regex to get just the filename of the first file returned by list:

```
ftp.list('D*.txt')[0][/.*(\d{2}):(\d{2})\s{1}(?<file>.+)$/,1]
```

Comment: That's correct, for example in Mainframe ftp service for datasets