# How to get FTP records in Ruby without first saving the text file and feed CSV with it

Tags: ruby, csv, ftp

I already get records from a ftp server with the gettextfile method and work on each record in the given block to finally put it elsewhere.

This file is a CSV file and I need to proceed it with CSV to get headers and datas and put it on DB after some work. As I have many different files, I need a generic way.
I don't want to load all records on memory or disk, because the files can be very big!
So a stream would be good

One idea is to give a io object to the CSV, but I don't see how to do that with Net::FTP.

I already see "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223763/how-to-ftp-in-ruby-without-first-saving-the-text-file" but it work with PUT.

Any help?

Comment: Any luck with this yet? I'm hoping to find a solution to that exact problem. related: [apidock thread](http://apidock.com/ruby/Net/FTP/gettextfile)

Answer (score 3):

The technique that Justin mentions creates a [temporary file](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/Net/FTP.html#method-i-gettextfile).

You could use [retrlines](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/Net/FTP.html#method-i-retrlines):

```
   filedata = ''
   ftp.retrlines("RETR " + filename) do |block|
      filedata << block
   end
```

or [retrbinary](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/Net/FTP.html#method-i-retrbinary) instead:

```
   filedata = ''
   ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + filename, Net::FTP::DEFAULT_BLOCKSIZE) do |block|
      filedata << block
   end
```

Comment: Nice learning... +1 Future reader [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255141/download-multiple-ftp-files-like-d-txt-in-ruby) if needed to make a complete program with this one...

Answer (score 1):

I think you're most of the way to the solution with gettextfile. You could just accumulate a portion of the file into an `Array`, and then process that with CSV when it reaches some threshold. Here is some untested code that processes ten lines at a time:

```rb
current_line = 0
chunk = []

ftp.gettextfile('file.csv') do |line|
  chunk << line
  process_chunk!(chunk) if current_line % 10 == 0
  current_line += 1
end

process_chunk!(chunk) # Any remaining lines in final partial chunk

def process_chunk!(lines_in_chunk)
  # process partial chunk of lines as if it were the whole file
  lines_in_chunk = []
end
```

That seems like one of the simpler solutions to me, but you could also probably work something up with multiple unix processes (writing to and reading from STDOUT) or Ruby threads in a producer-consumer model.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I came up with uses `IO.pipe`, a thread to iterate over lines of text from the FTP file (some of which may be row fragments inside of quotes) and `puts` each line to the IO writer.

In the main thread, I create a `CSV` instance based on the IO reader and iterate over the parsed rows from that.

```
require 'CSV'

def stream_ftp_csv_test(ftp, filename)
  read_io, write_io = IO.pipe

  fetcher = Thread.new do
    begin
      ftp.gettextfile filename do |line|
        write_io.puts line
      end
    ensure
      write_io.close
    end
  end

  csv = CSV.new(read_io, headers: :first_row)
  csv.each do |row|
    # Printing the row hashes here as an example.
    # You could yield each one to a given block
    # argument or whatever else makes sense.
    p row.to_h
  end

  fetcher.join
ensure
  read_io.close if read_io
end
```